# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on the null object reference

Tags: java, android, sql, nullpointerexception

Basically, I want to pick the "Name" entered at [RegisterActivity.java](https://www.codepile.net/pile/0Km6kJPV) which the user enters and transfer that to the [DashboardActivity.java](https://www.codepile.net/pile/1w0g7RPZ) when it opens.
I got an error at `line 51` and `line 116` in [dash.java](https://www.codepile.net/pile/1wgvKk9q).

What I tried:

- Tried `Name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);` instead of `Name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);` at `line 22`at [DashboardActivity.java](https://www.codepile.net/pile/1w0g7RPZ)
- When i remove the `line 116` logcat error gets removed and "[Name = null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvyMM.jpg)" comes; I want to replace `null` with text entered by the user.

`2019-10-20 20:42:40.868 18750-18750/com.example.seve E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.seve, PID: 18750
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.seve.dash.CheckEditTextStatus(dash.java:116)
        at com.example.seve.dash$1.onClick(dash.java:51)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6304)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24803)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)`

P.S: Saw atleast 8 similar questions regarding this and even referred to [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)


Still i was unable to find my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your Error log says that this `NullPointerException` is causing by an `EditText`. You are calling `getText()` function on an `EditText` which is not initialized yet (is null).

Comment: Post more code if you still can't solve the problem.